# Listing sql fields name with mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, linq-to-sql

i can with classic asp this method but not working c# mvc:

**classic asp**

```
 for each f in rs.Fields 

response.Write (f.Name)
```

**mvc this method**

```
var s = (from d in db.record.tolist());

     @foreach (var item in s)
    {
@item.name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx)  method which takes a string parameter.
By replacing table_name with your actual table name, you get all the columns.

```
var columnnames = typeof(table_name).GetProperties().Select(t => t.Name);

var columnnames = from t in Type.GetType(table_name).GetProperties() select t.Name;
```